# I can't filter data in hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, filter, hbase

I am trying to filter some data from HBase it's a measureTimestamp as string. Filtered values are beyond my range of filter; here is my code:

```
try {
    FilterList filters = new FilterList();

    Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
        Bytes.toBytes("measure"), 
        Bytes.toBytes("measureTimestamp"), 
        CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, 
        Bytes.toBytes("0000000100")); // ??column1???aaa?????
    filters.addFilter(filter);

    Filter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
        Bytes.toBytes("measure"), 
        Bytes.toBytes("measureTimestamp"), 
        CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, 
        Bytes.toBytes("0000015000"));
    filters.addFilter(filter1);

    Filter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
        Bytes.toBytes("measure"), 
        Bytes.toBytes("captor_id"), 
        CompareOp.EQUAL, 
        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("2")));
    filters.addFilter(filter2);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(filters);
    rs = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result r: rs) {
        System.out.println("Cle Ligne :" + new String(r.getRow()));
        for (KeyValue keyValue: r.raw()) {
            System.out.println("-" + new String(keyValue.getQualifier()) + " = : " + new String(keyValue.getValue()));
        }
    }
    rs.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

could anyone please help me thks.

Comment: Could you explain your problem more detailed? Whats wrong with your filtered values? Could your provide little example of your HBase data which alows to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I tried those special strings with in front 000 series because when I only compare values between a range of 100 and 15000 it has given results beyond this